# cambiar de icono por cada "Onclick" pero no ejecuta funcion de php

Tags: php, html, onclick

Función en php

```
$estado1 = 'imagenVerde';
$estado2 = 'imagenRoja';   
$estado3 = 'ImagenAzul';
$estadoA = $estado1;  

//funcion para cambiar el estado en un click

function cambia_estado($estado1,$estado3,$estadoA){

    if ($estadoA == $estado1)

    {
          $estadoA = $estado3;
        }

        elseif ($estadoA == $estado3) {
          $estadoA = $estado1;    
    }

}
```

Lo cual me debería devolver un nuevo valor del estadoA en cada click segun lo siguiente:

[image: 2 FORMAS DE CODIGO HTML QUE PROBE]

Comment: el onclick es un evento de javascript, no de php. incluye tu codigo html + js

Comment: Pero entonces porque si me funciona con una instruccion simple como : <td><a href="#"  onclick="<?php $estadoA = $estado3;?>"><?php $ASIENTO = 11; echo $estadoA;?></td>      MUCHAS GRACIAS SALUDOS

Comment: gracias por aclarar, es que estas mezclando los 2 lenguajes, en general siempre se recomienda tener tu html en un lado y tu php en otro lado. por cuestion de legibilidad.

Comment: lo que sucede es que si la ejecuta, pero luego que haces con esa variable ? ya que la funcion no retona nada, entonces no se ve reflejado que haga algo, }

Answer (score 0):

Como bien te dicen en los comentarios, onclick es un evento de JavaScript, y por ende, busca ejecutar código de JavaScript.

PHP es un lenguaje que funciona del *lado del servidor*. Las funciones en PHP se evalúan antes de mostrar tu página en pantalla, y son las que generan el HTML.

Por ejemplo, cuando ponés:

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="<?php $estadoA = $estado3;?>"><?php $ASIENTO = 11; echo $estadoA;?></td>
```

Esto debería traducirse en HTML:

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="">Contenido de estadoA</a></td>
```

Porque asigna antes de mostrar la página el valor de `estado3` a `estadoA`, el valor 11 a `asiento`, y finalmente hace `echo` del valor de `estadoA`, que es lo único que vas a ver en el HTML.

JavaScript por otra parte, ejecuta del *lado del cliente*. Por eso puede detectar eventos como `onclick`, y ejecutar código sin refrescar la página.

A diferencia del código de PHP, el código en JavaScript está en el navegador y se ejecuta allí. El usuario puede ver y modificar este código, por lo que para cuestiones que requieren seguridad, se usa PHP u otro lenguaje que funcione del lado del servidor.

No puedo responder qué debe ir adentro de tu `onclick`, ya que no me queda claro qué quieres lograr con el código, pero espero que esta diferenciación te ayude a seguir aprendiendo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, voy a intentar hacer la accion de ["onClick"] con codigo JavaScript  . Lo que espero que haga la accion ["onClick"] es que me cambie la variable ["estado A"] y le asigne el valor de ["estado3"] que vendria siendo una imagen en color azul, por su parte si la variable ["estadoA"] ya tiene el valor de ["estado3"] que mas bien le asigne en este caso el valor de ["estado1"] que vendria siendo una imagen del asiento en verde ...

Comment: .Es decir si la imagen esta en verde y le damos click se pasa a AZUL y si la imagen ya esta en AZUL por el contrario la pase a VERDE. Saludos y gracias por la ayuda de todos

Comment: Ojo, el tema es que tu variables $estadoA y $estado3 son de PHP. No son algo que puedas manejar con JS. Vas a tener que crear nuevas variables, y usarlas para modificar el atributo src de un <img>. Mezclar lenguajes puede ser un poco avanzado si todavía no te dieron ninguna clase...